# Kali Live: Partitions on /dev/sdb have been written, but we have been unable to inform kernel of the change, probably they are in use

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, kali-linux

I have downloaded a .iso from official kali web. Then used `Startup Disk Creator`, and reboot. I have enter kali installation process up to point where, `partitioning disks`. It suggested me to reboot, so I did. But then after entering boot menu, I have not seen usb bootloader (with kali) anymore. (So only windows manager). Can some please suggests, how to make boot menu to see my usb? Or do I have to use `disk creator` every time? Is there a command for it? Also, is the solution as 'only' rebooting for informing kernel about missing partitions, or will then another error arise?

Comment: Kali is absolutely not for beginners. Start on a more complete unix, switch to kali when you already know what you're doing. Compulsory kali link - [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: @DavidPostill, I don't remeber I asked you whether I should use kali or not. It is my decision. I only asked how to install it, not why to install it. So please answer to question and not to be off topic.

Comment: Clearly you haven't read the answers in the link I posted. Please read that before you start complaining.

Comment: "Kali Linux is a distribution for professional penetration testers who are already very familiar with Linux. It is meant to be used from a USB dongle for penetration testing. **It can be installed, but it is not really meant to be**. It is not meant for general use (even by professional penetration testers) such as Internet browsing, word processing, gaming, development, etc."

Comment: "**if you're a new user, getting used to Linux, people discourage you because it's the wrong choice, and do not wish to help you load your gun and shoot yourself in the foot.**"

Comment: I get it. You are not gonna help me anyway, that's ok. But then ... Do not please say these bullsh**s, either help me or leave it.

Comment: "Whether you’re new to infosec, or a seasoned security veteran, the free “Kali Linux Revealed” online course has something to teach you. The saying “You can’t build a great building on a weak foundation” rings true in the information security field as well, and if you use (or want to learn to use) Kali in a professional way, you should familiarise yourself as best as you can with the internals of the penetration testing distribution – and that’s what this training is all about – turning you into a Kali Linux professional user." ~ developers

Comment: @davidpostill, stop sending people to that. Even the first paragraph of the most upvoted answer is wrong. I suggest you read a little from the Kali Linux revealed handbook instead of sending people to a non-answer while clouding the comments section.

Comment: Besides, you have not even said, what is the definition of `I am able to use Kali, I am professional`.  You rather tell me the point of knowledge to have to use it, that would actually help me a bit. I have learnt perl scripting and being using c for kernel modules. I do not saying I am professional, but I am bored reading books with no purpose, practical use. No practical purpose. I have decided to installed Kali to actually do SOMETHING on purpose. So as I said, either help me, or leave it

Comment: @Tim_Stewart The problem is that the quality of the Kali questions posted here means that more that 60% go unanswered. And if you think that post is incorrect please head over there and correct it.

Comment: @davidpostill, why would I do that? Do we not also answer Kali questions here? That community clearly has some sort of grudge against Kali Linux. It takes only a few seconds to look at the u&l community Kali tag to see what I'm talking about. I get the low quality aspect of **a lot** of these questions. But pointing to that answer is not helpful at all IMHO. Most of these basic questions can be answered with the PDF honestly.